# Matrix3x2 Performance

Tags: c#, matrix

In my graphics application, I can represent matrices using either `SharpDX.Matrix3x2` or `System.Numerics.Matrix3x2`. However, upon running both matrices through a performance test, I found that SharpDX's matrices handily defeat `System.Numerics.Matrix3x2` by a margin of up to 70% in terms of time. My test was a pretty simple repeated multiplication, here's the code:

```
 var times1 = new List<float>();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var mat = SharpDX.Matrix3x2.Identity;

    for (var j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        mat *= SharpDX.Matrix3x2.Rotation(13);

    sw.Stop();

    times1.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
}

var times2 = new List<float>();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var mat = System.Numerics.Matrix3x2.Identity;

    for (var j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        mat *= System.Numerics.Matrix3x2.CreateRotation(13);

    sw.Stop();

    times2.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
}

TestContext.WriteLine($"SharpDX: {times1.Average()}\nSystem.Numerics: {times2.Average()}");
```

I ran these tests on an Intel i5-6200U processor.

Now, my question is, how can SharpDX's matrices possibly be faster? Isn't `System.Numerics.Matrix3x2` supposed to utilise SIMD instructions to execute faster?

The implementation of `SharpDX.Matrix3x2` is available [here](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Mathematics/Matrix3x2.cs), and as you can see, it's written in plain C#.

Comment: _" Isn't System.Numerics.Matrix3x2 supposed to utilise SIMD instructions to execute faster?"_ - [yes, but only for .NET 4.6 x64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/numerics#simd-enabled-vector-types).

Comment: Your timing is most likely flawed. Use a standard benchmarking library like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) to get accurate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my testing logic was flawed - I was creating the rotation matrix *inside* the loop, which meant that I was testing the creation of rotation matrices *and* multiplication. I revised my testing code to look like this:

```
var times1 = new List<float>();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var mat = SharpDX.Matrix3x2.Identity;

    var s = SharpDX.Matrix3x2.Scaling(13);
    var r = SharpDX.Matrix3x2.Rotation(13);
    var t = SharpDX.Matrix3x2.Translation(13, 13);

    for (var j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
    {
        mat *= s;
        mat *= r;
        mat *= t;
    }

    sw.Stop();

    times1.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
}

var times2 = new List<float>();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var mat = System.Numerics.Matrix3x2.Identity;

    var s = System.Numerics.Matrix3x2.CreateScale(13);
    var r = System.Numerics.Matrix3x2.CreateRotation(13);
    var t = System.Numerics.Matrix3x2.CreateTranslation(13, 13);

    for (var j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
    {
        mat *= s;
        mat *= r;
        mat *= t;
    }

    sw.Stop();

    times2.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
}
```

So that the only thing performed *inside* the loop was multiplication, and I began to receive results indicating better performance from `System.Numerics.Matrix3x2`.

Another point: I didn't pay attention to the fact that SIMD optimisations only take effect in 64-bit code. These are my test results before and after changing the platform to x64:

```
Platform Target | System.Numerics.Matrix3x2 | SharpDX.Matrix3x2
---------------------------------------------------------------
AnyCPU          | 168ms                     | 197ms
x64             | 1.40ms                    | 1.43ms
```

When I check `Environment.Is64BitProcess` under AnyCPU, it returns false - and the "Prefer 32-Bit" box in Visual Studio is greyed out, so I suspect that AnyCPU is just an alias for x86 in this case, which explains why the test is 2 orders of magnitude faster under x64.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other things you need to consider also with the testing.  These are just side notes, and wont affect your current results.  I've done some testing like this also.

Some corresponding functions in Sharpdx pass by object, not reference, there are corresponding by reference functions you might want to play with.  You've used the operators in your testing (all fine, its a comparable test!).  Just in some situations, use of operators is slower than the by reference functions.